# What could the Justice Department actually do with the Special Counsel’s report if it said the president likely committed a crime?

Tags: united-states, justice-department

I understand that the Justice Department can’t charge a sitting president with a crime, but what could they actually do if a special counsel like Mueller found that it seemed very likely the president committed a crime? Would they send the evidence to Congress, or would it just sit around in a cabinet forever?

Answer (score 4):

If the crimes were serious enough, they could defer prosecutorial actions (defer all aspects of prosecution, including an actual official criminal investigation and charges, if any were warranted) until the President was out of office, which would set up a scenario of the President trying to pardon himself, or possibly resigning in a Nixonian deal where the resignation is paired with the subsequent office-holder issuing a pardon, which might set up yet more investigations.

From what Mueller has said, and contrary to what Barr has offered, the entire structure of the Mueller report was a road map for Congress to use if they wanted to push forward with impeachment proceedings.

In that regard, what the Justice Department could do is offer the full, unredacted (or as much as can be not redacted) report to Congress, and offer to make members available for any formal impeachment proceedings to provide testimony.

Comment: According to the statement made by Mueller today, they cannot have a sealed indictment. All the examples of Nixon are moot because all the legal theories about what is constitutional have not been tested since Nixon resigned. And he was subsequently pardoned by Ford.  The only reason Nixon was in a position to make a deal with Ford was because the VP slot was vacant and Nixon had the choice of who to nominate for it.  In general, a President would not have such an opportunity to make a deal.

Comment: @grovkin: In that case, the statute of limitations would be tolled until the President leaves office in either 2020 or 2024. He could be indicted and prosecuted at that time. However, this would set up the political spectacle of the ex-President being arrested at or shortly after his successor's inauguration, which I imagine the DoJ would prefer to avoid.

Comment: @grovkin - I'm not stating they would have a sealed indictment ready to go. I'm stating they would go through the process of a formal criminal investigation on the former president once that person left office.  Ignore if there are some now-deleted comments between you and Kevin, and it was not my answer you were responding to. The "pardon" I refer to would be of the blank-check variety, for anything and everything done (as was issued to Nixon by Ford, and to the Iran Contra perpetrators by Bush the Senior, before any convictions or trials).

Comment: I see.  Maybe you could add it to the answer.  I didn't get that from the reading of it.

Comment: @grovkin - That's very helpful feedback. I made some edits, let me know if it still seems muddled or not.

Comment: I downvoted because Mueller did not make a referral to Congress, and a subsequent statement from the Office of Special Counsel Press Secretary said explicitly that the mere fact of the OLC ruling was mentioned did not mean that Mueller would have indicted Trump but for that ruling. Therefore, the idea that the report is a secret passive aggressive impeachment roadmap for Congress to play with is not supported by direct statements from Mueller or his office, and is a kind of speculation as to his internal motivations.

Comment: @Joe isn't that the reason to downvote the question rather than the answer?  The answer is just addressing the question, even if the question's premise is sketchy.

Comment: re: deferring prosecution until after the President is out of office.  The edit is clear enough.  But it maybe worth elaborating on it.  Apparently [Bill Clinton was in fact in such jeopardy](https://web.archive.org/web/20150527165047/https://www.nytimes.com/2001/01/20/opinion/mr-clinton-s-last-deal.html) which is why he made a deal on the last day of his presidency to avoid a token conviction on his record after leaving office.

Comment: @grovkin No, there is no unfounded assumption about Mueller's internal state of mind or secret, unstated plan to solicit impeachment in the question.

Comment: @Joe are you talking about the 2nd paragraph?

Comment: @grovkin Yes, that's what I'm talking about.

Comment: @Joe - have you read the report, or listened to what Mueller said in his press conference? Nowhere do I claim that Mueller is suggesting that Congress impeach, I'm saying that, since he can't charge, he lays out everything he has, and leaves it up to Congress to decide. Mueller specifically stated that the reason they could not even consider making a recommendation was the ruling, period. Combine that with "if we found he was exonerated, we would have so stated. We did not." Barr claimed that they did not recommend because they did not find the evidence to do so. Mueller directly refuted that.

Comment: @Joe - as far as "speculation," - "With respect to whether the President can be found to have obstructed justice by exercising his powers under Article II of the Constitution, **we concluded that Congress has authority to prohibit a President’s corrupt use of his authority in order to protect the integrity of the administration of justice**,” - there's no need to speculate or try to read his mind, he specifically says it's up to Congress to act, and that was never going to be something that could have fallen to him.

Answer (score 2):

Robert Mueller finally made a statement about his report today, 5/29/19.  The statement was very short (~10 mins).  And it was so universally covered, that I won't try to link to it.

According to the statement made by Robert Mueller today, special counsel cannot indict a sitting President nor can it produce a sealed indictment (an indictment secretly held until a future date with the purpose of waiting out a temporary immunity while not running up against a statute of limitations).

Robert Mueller stated that this DOJ guidance is due to the fact that indicting a sitting President would be unconstitutional.  Because this question has never been taken up by SCOTUS, this is currently the most authoritative answer on the subject.

Referring it to Congress is the only course of action available to a special counsel.

A point which maybe worth noting is that the special counsel Mueller's office did ***not make a Congressional referral***.  While Ken Starr's report was referred to Congress.  Obviously people will argue that this is due to them having different offices and responsibilities (Starr was an Independent Counsel while Mueller was a Special Counsel).  But Mueller **did have the option of making a referral**.

A number of people have suggested that the language which Mueller used suggested that he was making a referral.  But that is simply not the case.

He made a number of prosecution referrals during the course of the investigation.  So making referrals outside of his office was within the scope of his powers.

He could have simply made the referral if he thought it was appropriate.  He did not.

Comment: BTW, what Mueller should have said was ' a group of lawyers at DOJ opined that indictment of a sitting president would be unconstitutional' and I am not the lawyer to challenge that opinion, which would allow the judges to establish what is unconstitutional.

Comment: @BobE He clearly did not want to editorialize. Also, it's more than merely a "group of lawyers at DOJ."  It's the legally accepted standard of the DOJ.  To suggest it would be up to a court to make this decision would imply that a court should be making this decision.  And a court only makes decisions when there is an existing case before the court.  Such a suggestion *could* be interpreted that Mueller thought there should be a case before the court.  And it almost certainly *would* be interpreted this way by anyone wishing to stretch it in that direction.

Comment: u said "To suggest it would be up to a court to make this decision would imply that a court should be making this decision."  The decision on constitutionality is made by the courts, not by the OLC.

Comment: @BobE courts opine on constitutionality when there is lack of clarity and a case which turns on the point which needs clarification is presented to a court.  If there is no lack of clarity or no challenge exists, the current practice stands as definitive.

Comment: Well you and I will just have to disagree on whether courts opine or declare on issues of constitutionality. My point is only that the proper body to sit in judgement on constitutionality is judiciary. The OLC memo is guidance for the DOJ, it has no force of law on it's own, as contrasted with a Court order, which has the force of law. Recommend reading the OLC memo that concludes that prosecution would "unduly interfere with the ability of the executive branch " to perform it's duties.

Comment: @BobE the courts clarify on issues of constitutionality when there is a disagreement.  They do it by issuing opinions (which is what it means to "opine").  They don't act as a certification authority for all laws.  The DOJ guidance is based on the best current understanding of all legal issues involved.  That includes all constitutional issues.  Until there is a case testing the current understanding, the current DOJ guidance is an instruction manual, of sorts, for where the law currently stands.  If a new court opinion changes the law, that is reflected in the guidance.

Comment: @BobE it's not that anyone is arguing that this is the current law because the DOJ guidance says it is.  The converse is true.  The DOJ guidance is made so as to reflect the current understanding of what the law is.  And *short of a court ruling*, it is the most definitive understanding available.

Comment: @BobE maybe I can make this even shorter.  This DOJ guidance is the current understanding of the law *unless it is changed by a court*, which is not the same as *until it is affirmed or changed by a court*.

Comment: "It is emphatically the province of the judicial department to say what the law is." -Chief Justice Marshall, Marbury v Madison. The DOJ is executive branch, not Judicial.

Comment: @BobE and yet that's not how the system is set up.  when legislature is passed, it doesn't automatically go to SCOTUS to certify that it's constitutional.  But, if the law changes USC, DOJ does have to create guidance (a manual) for its attorneys to know how to apply the newly passed law.  **Marshall's quote means that the court has the last word in what the law means**.  But the law has to be applied even before SCOTUS weighs in and even if SCOTUS decides to never weigh in on a particular law.

Comment: Here's the problem - the DOJ policy is not the law, it's just guidance. It has nothing to do with legislated law.

Comment: @BobE DOJ is part of the executive.  Which quite literally means they have to execute the law.  The guidelines are there as a manual so they know how to execute the law.  They can't just read it and wing it.  They need to consider all precedent and have a plan for what to do when it comes to enforcement.  It doesn't make sense to say "it has nothing to do with legislated law."  It's the rule book that the people who enforce the law use to understand what the law means.

Comment: Getting far afield here - Can you cite for me the relevant section of the Justice Manual that covers presidential indictment?

Comment: @BobE https://www.justice.gov/file/19351/download

Comment: that is the latest version of the Memo Opinion, what I was looking for is some citation from the DOJ Justice Manual (formerly known as the US Attorney's Manual), it would be there where the "rules" are laid out.

Comment: @BobE the problem here is that because the justice department has decided that it cannot prosecute a sitting president, and the justice department is the only federal agency that can prosecute *anyone,* the only way the question could end up in a court would be for the justice department to change its mind.

Comment: agreed, and the (reasonable) plaintiff in such a action would be the sitting president.